# How to set font family to edit-text with data-binding layout in Android

Tags: android, data-binding

I Create a data model for my activity like this:

```
data class ActivityModel (
    var font: Int
)
```

And set the value to this **font** in the activity as this way:

```
items.font = R.font.san_francisco
```

And finally, use it in XML layout like this:

```
android:fontFamily="@{ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, items.font)}"
```

also I import this varriables to XML layout:

```
    <import type="androidx.core.content.ContextCompat"/>
    <import type="androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat"/>
```

But in this way, the app doesn't be building and I have errors from **java (generated)** directory.

So, How can I set the font family to edit-text?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using binding adapter as follow :

1- create fonts types as enum class to include all your fonts:

```
enum class FontsTypes(@FontRes val fontRes: Int) {
    CAIRO_REGULAR(R.font.font_cairo_regular),
    CAIRO_BOLD(R.font.font_cairo_bold),
    CAIRO_SEMI_BOLD(R.font.font_cairo_semi_bold)
}
```

2- create a binding adapter fun :

```
@BindingAdapter("font")
fun TextView.font( type: FontsTypes) {
    try {
        typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, type.fontRes)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

3- import FontsTypes inside xml :

```
<data>      
  <import type="<replace_with_path>.FontsTypes"/>
</data>
```

4- call it from xml :

```
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            font="@{model.selected ? FontsTypes.CAIRO_BOLD : FontsTypes.CAIRO_SEMI_BOLD }" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using func getIdentifier to get font res from font name (in my case, font has located in res/font folder):

```
fun Context.retrievingResources(resourceName: String, resourceType: String): Int {
return resources.getIdentifier(resourceName, resourceType, packageName);
```

}

function in binding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:font")
fun setFont(textView: TextView, fontName: String) {
textView.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(textView.context, textView.context.retrievingResources(fontName, "font"))
```

}

and using in data binding xml file:

```
app:font="@{model.selected ?`fontNameStringWithoutFileExtension1` : `fontNameStringWithoutFileExtension2`}"
```